# autoattribute for parallel assignment of instance variables

Tags: python, python-sphinx, instance-variables, docstring, autodoc

When documenting instance variables, I can do

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spam = 4
        """Docstring for instance attribute spam."""
```

This doesn't work for parallel assignment

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spam, self.bar, self.moo = 4, 5, 6
        """Docstring for instance attribute spam."""
```

How can I document variables in parallel assignment?

Comment: Neither one of those does anything at all. You just have random string literals in your method; they are not docstrings. If you want comments, use comments.

Comment: These are for sphinx. It will look over these and generate doc for me.

Comment: sphinx seems very broken to me, then. in any case, if sphinx doesn't let you write docstrings for parallel assignments... maybe don't do parallel assignments?

Answer (score 0):

[`autoattribute`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute) is for a single attribute. Here is a way to do it, together with `autoclass` or `automodule`:

```
class Foo:
    """
    :ivar spam: Description of spam
    :ivar bar: Description of bar
    :ivar moo: Description of moo
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.spam, self.bar, self.moo = 4, 5, 6
```

The output looks a bit different compared to what you get with `autoattribute`, but I quite like it.

Comment: This will look different than using autoattribute

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use Sephix markup inside the `__init__` doc string block and make it look almost the same as using autoattribute.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Something something

        .. py:attribute:: spam

           Something about spam

        .. py:attribute:: bar

           Something about br

        .. py:attribute:: moo

           Something about moo
        """
        self.spam, self.bar, self.moo = 4, 5, 6
```

This will look like 
http://xrxr.github.io/RapidPygame/levelmgr.html 
(interpreted and draw_list is done using this technique.)
if `autoclass_content` is set to `'both'`
(If you pay attention, they are not in their right alphabetical place)

This works, but I still wonder if there is a better way.